# How can I install TensorFlow version 2.2?

Tags: python, tensorflow

How can I install TensorFlow versions 2.2.0? I need to use this version for ONNX.

When I try:

```
pip install tensorflow==2.2.0
```

I get the following error:

> Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.2.0 (from versions: 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.7.4, 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0rc0, 2.11.0rc1, 2.11.0rc2, 2.11.0)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.2.0

Comment: Are you using a compatible version of python? It supports 3.5-3.8 (see [here](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.2.0/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly mentioned by **Plagon**, you need to install `python version` between `3.5 to 3.8` to support the `TensorFlow version 2.2` as mentioned in this [tested bulid configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu) below.

[image]